# Redirect to Angular internal route from external Application

Tags: javascript, angular

I am building my authentication system as a different front end application than my dashboard application. The front end auth app is hosted in lets say [http://auth.example.net](https://example.net) and front end of dashboard app is hosted in http://dashboard.example.net.

Router structure of my dashboard :

```
{
    path: "dashboard",
    component: LandingPageComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'home'
      },
      {
        path: "home",
        component: HomeComponent,
        canActivate: [RouteGuard],
        data: {
          externalUrl: authFrontEnd
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'Contact',
        component: ContactComponent,
        canActivate: [RouteGuard],
        data: {
          externalUrl: authFrontEnd
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'about',
        component: AboutComponent,
        canActivate: [RouteGuard],
        data: {
          externalUrl: authFrontEnd
        }
      }
    ],
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: ":user/:token", component: AuthenticationComponent },
```

In my auth application, When I am authenticated, I should be redirected to the Dashboard application's url with userId and token embedded in the url (I know its not a secure way to do):[http://dashboard.example.net/user_2/token_ec23](https://example.net)

**In my Auth app**:

```
loginAuthentication(user) {

   const result = this.apiService.login(user);
   result.subscribe(res=> {
     if(res.status === 'success') {
       window.location.href=`http://dashboard.example.net/${res.result.user_id}/${res.result.token}`
    }
   })
}
```

From what I understand is, this isn't working because the angular routes are only understood inside the angular application. Redirection to angular internal routes can't be happening from external source. How to achieve this thing ? The requirement for me is to pass the token and user Id from auth application to dashboard application and this is the only way I know for now.

Comment: Is is it possible to communicate with auth server in the back end only?

Comment: Do you mean that the authentication UI should be handled by the backend ? In the above problem when I say App, it only means the Front end. Backend services are handling the api's

Comment: Sorry my question doesn't make sense really now that I think about it. Does the UI component of authentication have to be component of other app?

Comment: No. The Front end of Auth app and dashboard app is completely exclusive of each other. Both are deployed in different servers. However when authentication is successfull, I need to redirect the front end to the dashboard app. In the dashboard, I need to check if the user is authenticated before letting him pass inside the application. So I will be needing the token sent from the auth app

Comment: I think I can not achieve this with only front end. Backend code also might have be involved to fix this

Comment: Yes, have both backends communicate with each other

Comment: No, it doesn't as such. Just to check the token i am hitting the api of authentication app from dashboard app. Auth backend takes care of the authentication. and send backs a token. redirection happens in the front end once token is received.

Comment: What happens right now when you try and visit your link to 'http://dashboard.example.net/user_2/token_ec23'
Which page do you currently land on?

Comment: when my app is deployed to server application not found is showing. The application deployment itself is throwing errors